# Redimensionamiento de espacio en linux

Tags: linux, servidor, debian

Hola grupo tengo muchos problemas con el espaciado del un servidor debian, quisiera aumentar el tamaño de mi esapcio raiz, primeramente utilizo un virtualizador proxmox con el cual cree una maquina virtual de espacio de 10GB y instale debian 9 para el arranque del servidor pero al darme cuenta añadi 10GB para un espaciado mas amplio.
[image: Aumento de espacio]

luego al inicar nuevamente el servicio realize el fdisk -l
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve el aumento de disco se efectua paso de 10GB a 20GB pero este cambio no se efectua en el disco, buscando informacion encontre el uso de una herramienta denominada "parted" herramienta utilizada para el redimensionamiento de espacio, al colocar las instrucciones print .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y para el espacio libre me muestra 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se el parece que el esapcio esta detras de las particiones primaria el extend y logical, el problemas que al aumentar el espacio me muestra el error que no se puede sobreescribir la ampliacion ya que el /dev/sda1 se sobreescribira en el /dev/sda2 y /dev/sda5 debido a que su inicio y fin de escritura entrarian en conflicto como puedo añadir espacio /dev/sda1 y recorrer los espacios /dev/sda2 y /dev/sda5 mas atras para que permita la ampliacion de disco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No utilizaste LVM? Porque entonces está complicado dentro del propio sistema, tendrías que aprovechar la virtualización y usar desde fuera del debian (sin bootear) parted

Comment: ese es punto mis conocimientos son muy flacos en lo que respecta a LVM

Comment: Ah perfecto entonces sólo usa el redimensionado del volumen lógico con lvextend: https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-increase-an-lvm-partition/